# Cross domain SignalR does not work when issued form another computer

Tags: signalr

I have two MVC application in separate domains which one (csm.mywebsite.com) calls a client function, using signalR, on the other (ess.mywebsite.com). It works fine when I test it using two browser at same development machine. but when I try to call the function in one machine from a different machine, it fails and nothing just happens. both development machines have these applications on TFS.

server side Configuration code in csm.mywebsite.com:

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
}

public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
            {
            };
            map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        });

    }
}
```

I use following code to call the client function from server:

```
GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub> 
().Clients.User(userID.ToString()).SendMessage(message, "CSM");
```

and the client side on the other domain (ess.mywebsite.com)

```
$(document).ready(function () 

    $.getScript('http://csm.mywebsite.com/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.1.min.js', function () {
        $.getScript('http://csm.mywebsite.com/signalr/hubs', function () {

            $.connection.hub.url = 'http://csm.mywebsite.com/signalr';
            var notificationHub = $.connection.notificationHub;
            console.log(notificationHub);

            $.connection.hub.start();

            notificationHub.client.sendMessage = function (content, system) {

               alert(content);
            };
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I ignored the fact that each developing machine has project source stored locally. Then it's normal not to have clients form other machines subscribed. thus, no client function can be called from other machines. I deployed latest updates to server and everything works just fine.